# Adding key/value in existing Array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, google-tag-manager

I am trying to add a new KEY/VALUE into existing Array. I am having difficulties because ive seen other answers but did not work.

This is my Array in JSON:

```
[
{
accountId: "*****",
containerId: "******",
name: "Container23",
},
{
accountId: "**",
containerId: "*",
name: "Container2"
},
{
accountId: "*",
containerId: "*",
name: "Container1",
}
]
```

Other answer says i have to do this:

```
$containers[] = $account['name'];
```

But gives me wrong result, this is not adding the new value into exisiting key/value json object but rather adds it on top of it like this:

```
"Account2",                          <------- ??
{
accountId: "1746756959",
Name: "Account2",                    <---- Here is where i want to add it
name: "Container2"    
},
```

This is my code in PHP:

```
  static public function listAllContainers() {
        $containers = array();
        foreach (self::listAccounts()->account as $account) {
            foreach (self::listAccountsContainers($account["path"]) as $container) {
                $containers[] = $container;
              //$containers[] = $account['name'];        <--- Dont work
            }
        }
        return $containers;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
[image]

Comment: That's not even valid `JSON` that you want to create

Comment: It's valid, i havent taken the whole block

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in `json`

Comment: What do you mean, where is duplicate keys?

Comment: ah i see. so can you write your foreach codes for this image output?

Comment: @MertSimsek ive used your foreach code just commented out the second line in foreach(listaccountcointainers). Ive commented out:  $containers[$account['name']][] = $account['name'];    then i got it right, but still outside the object not inside like i wanted in image :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
static public function listAllContainers() {
        $containers = array();
        foreach (self::listAccounts()->account as $accountKey => $account) {
            foreach (self::listAccountsContainers($account["path"]) as $container) {
                $containers[$account['name']][] = $container;       
            }
        }
        return $containers;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Mert, this still gives me Account['name'] on top of object not inside.

Comment: Almost... ive updated my question and added a image so you can see

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the proper way to solve your issue, but it's fun

```
$json_data = '[
{
"accountId": "*****",
"containerId": "******",
"name": "Container23"
},
{
"accountId": "**",
"containerId": "*",
"name": "Container2"
},
{
"accountId": "*",
"containerId": "*",
"name": "Container1"
}
]';
```

The quick and dirty way is

```
$key='newKey';
$val='newVal';
json_decode(str_replace('{','{"'.$key.'":"'.$val.'",',$json_data));
```